# Comparing current date (Java) to a Timestamp in a DB (sql) using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to check if an entry to the DB has occurred today. My Query works when I run it with MySqlWorkbench, but when I use hibernate the query does not seem to work correctly I am always returned `true` even though the DB does have dates today.

The query is: 
    `@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN (count(ent) < 1) then true else false end 
    FROM Entity ent WHERE ent.createdAt >= (?1)")
    boolean checkIfEnteredToday(Date date);`

The `date` is from the java.sql.Date library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the DataType of The entity's datetype for 'created_at' to java.sql.Date, whereas previously it was java.sqlTimestamp.